# VS 2013 azure cloud debugger already attach

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging, azure-worker-roles

In visual studio 2013 after publish a new projet to azure cloud I try to attach the debug but get this error :
[image]

Steps:

1. New project : Azure cloud Service
2. Add worker only
3. Publish to my azure account with 'remote debugging' enabled
4. visualstudio/server explorer/azure/cloudservice click right on the instance of worker role => attach debugger
5. Attach to the process "WaWorkerHost.exe"

then I get the error..
Any idea ?
thank you

Comment: What version of the Azure SDK do you have installed?

Comment: @DaveKidder the version of sdk is 2.5

Comment: Have you stopped and restarted the cloud service?

Comment: @DaveKidder in the step 5 If I attach to the process "msvsmon" instead "WaWorkerHost.exe". I don't have any error and VS start debug. BUT Symbols are not load and not hit ? Am I on the good way or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to :

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/862890/attach-debuger-for-azure-web-sites-unable-to-attach-to-application-w3wp-exe-pid-xx-using-xxx-4018-the-visual-studio-debugger-cannot-establish-a-dcom-connection

So the solution is :

This issue is caused by having 'Use Managed Compatibility Mode' enabled. To workaround:

1. List item
2. Tools->Options
3. Go to Debugging->General
4. Scroll down to the bottom of the list and uncheck 'Use Managed Compatibility Mode'
5. Start debugging again

Unbelievable!